# Proof of Morera's Theorem for Triangular Contours

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, contour-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

Sorry if this has been proven previously on MSE but I cannot find an obvious duplicate. I am attempting to prove the stronger version of Morera's theorem namely:

> If $f:U\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ is a continuous function on an open set $U$ such
> that $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0$ for all triangular contours $\gamma$ contained in $U$, then $f$ is holomorphic on $U$.

**Proof (attempt):**

Let $a\in U$. Since $U$ is open, $\exists\,r\gt0$ such that $B(a,r)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-a|\lt r\}\subseteq U$. Now consider $f$ restricted to the domain $B(a,r)$. Using the given assumptions, this restriction of $f$ is continuous and satisfies $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0$ for all triangular contours $\gamma$ contained in $B(a,r)$. Then we can define $F:B(a,r)\mapsto\mathbb{C}$ by
$$F(z)=\int_{[a,z]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w$$
where $[a,z]$ is the line segment from $a$ to $z$ in $\mathbb{C}$. This function is now well-defined as $B(a,r)$ is connected. Next we can calculate
\begin{align}
F'(z)
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{F(z+h)-F(z)}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{[a,z+h]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w-\int_{[a,z]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\overbrace{\int_{[a,z+h]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w+\int_{[z+h,z]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w+\int_{[z,a]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}^{=\int_\gamma f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w=0}+\int_{[z,z+h]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\int_{[z,z+h]}f(w)\,\mathrm{d}w}h\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h\int_0^1f(z+ht)\cdot h\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\lim_{h\to0}\int_0^1f(z+ht)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^1\lim_{h\to0}f(z+ht)\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\int_0^1f(z)\,\mathrm{d}t\qquad(f\text{ continuous})\\
&=f(z)\\
\end{align}
Thus $F$ is holomorphic on $B(a,r)$ with derivative $f$. So, in particular, we can apply Cauchy's differentiation formula to give
$$f'(a)=F''(a)=\frac1{\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{F(z)}{(z-a)^3}\mathrm{d}z$$
for a suitable contour $\gamma$. But $a\in U$ was chosen arbitrarily and hence $f$ is holomorphic on $U$.

Comment: Sorry for reviving this thread again but can someone clarify why is this a _stronger_ version of Morera's Theorem? I studied Conway's text and this was the only version he introduces in Chapter-IV except with "holomorphic" replaced by "analytic".

Comment: @sadman-ncc Morera's Theorem usually assumes that $\int_\gamma f(z)\,\mathrm{d}z=0$ for $\gamma$ being any closed curve to obtain the conclusion. Since we only assume the much weaker assumption of $\gamma$ being triangular, the result is much stronger overall. If it holds assuming triangular contours, it certainly holds assuming unrestricted contours.

Comment: why does this work for triangles? where have you used triangles ? someone pls explain. if maybe trapeziums is given instead of triangles why wouldnt the same proof work ?

Comment: @Maou In the third line of working I equate the sum of three line integrals to zero which relies on the equivalent integral over a triangular contour being zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks good. Hope the following adds something.

1. Regarding the computation of the derivative $F'$, an alternative using triangle inequality: We have from your formulas for $h\neq 0$ $$\dfrac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h}-f(z)=\frac{1}{h}\int_{[z,z+h]}\{f(\zeta)-f(z)\}d\zeta$$ Now by continuity of $f$, given $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|\zeta-z|<\delta\Rightarrow |f(\zeta)-f(z)|<\epsilon$ so for $0<|z+h-z|=|h|<\delta$ we get using triangle inequality for contours $$|\dfrac{F(z+h)-F(z)}{h}-f(z)|\le\frac{1}{h} \max{|f(\zeta)-f(z)|}_{\zeta\in [z,z+h]}.h<\epsilon$$
2. In the end instead of using Cauchy's formula, we can use the fact that derivative of holomorphic is holomorphic (from what I have seen the Cauchy formulas follow from this in composition with the usual formula): We see that $F\in Hol(B(a,r))$ as a result. And so $F'=f\in Hol(B(a,r))$. Now since $a$ was arbitrary we are done.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Your point $(1)$ is quite helpful because I was unsure of the justification for the exchange of the limit and integral in my working but I have seen the triangle inequality before. Interestingly for your point $(2)$ I believe in my course they use Cauchy's formula to imply that holomorphic functions are infinitely differentiable but this was effectively what I was trying to prove with what I was given.

Comment: @PeterForeman Your integral was independent of $h$ so the limit exchange was justified. I used Stein-Shakarachi during my course & the layout was like couchy integral formula then holomorphic's derivative holomorphic then using the two getting the general derivative's integral formula. Anyways you are right.

Comment: I believe I would still need to apply say the Dominated Convergence theorem though. Or use that $f(z+ht)\to f(z)$ uniformly.

Comment: @PeterForeman since you were on the compact line $[z,z+h]$ all the time the continuity was uniform. (hope I am right)